# Make an array of random unique numbers in a certain range

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I'm working on a school project and I need to create an array (size of 30)
of random unique numbers between 1 and 70.

I managed to find how to create an array of random unique numbers, but not between 1 and 70.

```
public int[] ShuffleArray(int[] arr)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[70];
    for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
        array[i] = i + 1;
    int[] MyRandomArray = array.OrderBy(x => rand.Next(1, 71)).ToArray();
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.Length; k++)
        arr[k] = MyRandomArray[k];
    return arr;
}
```

I changed it based on feedback, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This information is easily accessible already on Google.  What have you tried already?

Comment: There's a _lot_ of existing questions about that already. Generate all the choices, shuffle them and take the first 30.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question to be much more specific and adding your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three steps are:

1. Generate all the choices
2. Shuffle them
3. Take the first 30

Looks like you got 1 and 2 covered So currently you have 70 numbers, in random order. What's left is the step 3, taking the first 30.

You can achieve it with [`Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It returns an `IEnumerable`, so you can use `ToArray` to transform it into an array afterwards.

```
return MyRandomArray.Take(30).ToArray();
```

So with the code you had, it would look like this:

```
public int[] ShuffleArray(int[] arr)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i;
    int[] array = new int[70];

    for (i = 0; i < 70; i++)
        array[i] = i + 1;

    int[] MyRandomArray = array.OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).ToArray();

    return MyRandomArray.Take(30).ToArray();
}
```

---

While we're here, let's fix a couple things too.

You can join the declaration and use of `i` in your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
```

In C#, the convention is to have variables written in camelCase, so `MyRandomArray` should be named `myRandomArray`.

You could abbreviate your `for` loop with the following:

```
int[] array = Enumerable.Range(1,70).ToArray();
```

Finally, if you want to really optimize things, you could join that declaration with the `OrderBy` and `Take` in a single line to drop the temporary variables:

```
public int[] ShuffleArray(int[] arr)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 70).OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).Take(30).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it works. can you tell me why my own code does not work?

Comment: @Daniel in the lastest edit you did, you're missing the array declaration: `int[] arr = new int[30];`. You should also revert the `rand.Next(1, 71)` to `rand.Next()`. In your first edit, it's because you were returning all 70 numbers.

Comment: I have the array decleration in a c# page where I call the method, but I didn't know about rand.next, thanks :) and I'm sorry if it's a common question I'm new here and they don't teach that at school.

Comment: @Daniel No problem, just remember to be the most specific you can while asking questions and include your code, like you did in your edits. Otherwise it's pretty hard to help.

Comment: Side note: this is valid copy-paste ready solution to homework, but if you found this post for some other reason it is wrong approach to shuffling array (proper code is O(n), while `OrderBy` solution is obviously `O(n log n)`, also proper code does not need to shuffle the rest - only 30 numbers). Make sure to search for `C# shuffle` for proper solution.

Comment: Indeed, an OrderBy with a `Random` or `new Guid` won't be as good as the Fisher-Yates or equivalent shuffles. It is a sub-optimal solution but will work for non-official contexts. A good implementation can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp)